# Defining a generic unfoldr function

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming, unfold

```swift
func unfoldr<A, B>(_ f: @escaping (B) -> (A, B)?) -> (B) -> UnfoldFirstSequence<A> {
    return { b in sequence(
        first: b, next: { x in
                switch f(x) {
                case .some(let(a, b)):
                    return Optional(a)
                default:
                    return Optional.none
            }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

With this definition, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'B' to expected argument type 'A'.
```

Is there some way of solving this issue and definining this function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequence doesn't seem to be a `UnfoldFirstSequence`. Your sequence seems to have a state `B`, and `f` is responsible for producing a new state and an element for the sequence.  An `UnfoldFirstSequence` has no state that you can control. You can only produce the next element from the previous element.

Your sequence can be modelled by the more general [`UnfoldSequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unfoldsequence), which has a `State` generic parameter. In fact, an `UnfoldFirstSequence<T>` is just an `UnfoldSequence<T, (T?, Bool)>`! See why the former is a special case of the latter by [reading the source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a73a8087968f9111149073107c5242d83635107a/stdlib/public/core/UnfoldSequence.swift#L43) :)

You can create such a sequence using [`sequence(state:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2011998-sequence).

```
func unfoldr<A, B>(_ f: @escaping (B) -> (A, B)?) -> (B) -> UnfoldSequence<A, B> {
    return {
        sequence(state: $0) { x in
            guard let (a, b) = f(x) else { 
                return nil 
            } 
            x = b 
            return a
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let seq = unfoldr { x -> (String, Int)? in
    if x == 10 {
        return nil
    } else {
        return ("\(x)", x + 1)
    }
}
seq(0).forEach { print($0) }
```

Comment: Interesting suggestion, @Leo Dabus. Could you tell me more about it ?

Comment: Understood, @Sweeper. Thank you for your comprehensive answer ! Solved my problem and also was instructive !